# Angular wait for first function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to wait for my first function results before execute second one.

## code

First function

```
getUser() {
    this.authService.user().subscribe(
        user => {
        this.user = user;
        console.log('current user 1: ', user);
        console.log('current user 2: ', this.user);
        }
    );
}

async ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.fromEvent('message').subscribe(async (message: any) => {
        if(this.user === undefined) {
            // first function called
            this.getUser();
            // before it finish this console log will fire, therefore it returns `undefined`
            console.log('this user: ', this.user);
        } else {
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

I need to hold my console call till `this.getUser();` is done. **How to do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your getUser() method to a promise.. like this..

```
getUser():Promise<any>{
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
     this.authService.user().toPromise().then(user => {
       this.user = user;
       console.log('current user 1: ', user);
       console.log('current user 2: ', this.user);
       resolve(user);
     }).catch(err=> reject(err));
   });
}
```

Then in your ngOnInit()

```
async ngOnInit(){
  this.socket.fromEvent('message').subscribe((message: any) => {
    if(this.user === undefined) {
        // first function called
        await this.getUser().then(user=>{
           console.log('this user: ', user);
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Also, try using toPromise(), where you need data from an observer only once.. subscribing to an observer and then not unsubscribing it will lead to memory leaks..

Comment: Mixing promises and RxJs is frowned upon by many. It is not wrong, but many people including myself would rather see a pure RxJs solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use combineLatest

```
combineLatest(this.authService.user(), this.socket.fromEvent('message'))
  .subscribe(([user, message]) => {
    // Both message and user are available at the same time
  });
```

Comment: I think not, see as my code is in `ngOnInit` if I do your way it will call for both of these instantly, I need to call for user ONLY if I have socket event Or i'm mistaking?

Comment: If one call relies on another you can use switchMap `this.socket.fromEvent('message').pipe(switchMap(message => functionThatReturnsAnObservable(message)))`

Comment: sorry I am not that pro in angular and this half codes just makes me more confused :D

Comment: My advise is that you are not ready to start learning Angular yet, Angular is built upon RxJs. Stop learning Angular for a day or two and go get familiar with RxJs. I wish somebody gave me this advise in the beginning as the apps I first wrote a few years ago would have been structured very differently if I knew more about RxJs at the time. Yes it seems confusing at first but it is the greatest improvement to asynchronous development in a long time.

Comment: https://rxmarbles.com/ is a great site that made many of the concepts click once I saw them visually

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like below use await and i hope it will solve your problem

```
async ngOnInit() {
this.socket.fromEvent('message').subscribe(async (message: any) => {
    if(this.user === undefined) {
        // first function called
        await this.getUser();
        // before it finish this console log will fire, therefore it returns `undefined`
        console.log('this user: ', this.user);
    } else {
        //....
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, after build finish i'll let you know the result

Comment: getUser doesn't return anything, it would need to return a promise for await to work

Comment: as Adrian mentioned it returns nothing.